# Does upgrading Ubuntu risk the loss of important data?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, upgrade, uninstall, files

I currently use Ubuntu 10.04, and I want to upgrade it to version 12.04 (and then, maybe, to 13.04). I can do it via Upgrade Manager, but I'm worried that my important files (which are in the home folder) could be removed. I also have many files (circa 50 GB) on another hard disk (it's a different disk than the one on which I have installed Ubuntu) - are they safe?

Last but not least, I've installed Windows XP (so I can choose my system via grub) and I want to know whether it will be still there, or will it be removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes all your files are completely safe when you upgrade, only the Ubuntu system files will change.

But make a backup of your important files so you don't lose them if the upgrade fails. You should always have your important files backup, it doesn't matter if it's on a cloud storage, usb-stick or on a hard drive just back it up somewhere.

Comment: "Yes all your files are completely safe when you upgrade"  should say "The upgrade process will not modify your files."

Comment: @TheLordOfTime your files are safe when you upgrade but if the upgrade fails they may not be so easy to get to. That's why you should always make backups!

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me one thing more - what with Windows? Will it remain? PS: sorry for my English.

Comment: @Bill yes your windows will be safe and Ubuntu will only touch the ubuntu system files. Everything will remain as it was before with your Windows and user files. But if you have important stuff, back them up!

Comment: @Bill Accept my answer if it solved your question, so future users can find the working answer more easily! thanks :)